# ext.net code not working while showing view

Tags: extjs, ext.net

I am trying to use ext.net to develop a asp.net application. I have configured web.config as directed in the instructions provided by ext.net. But when I run the application even though there is no errors shown the view is not showing the ext.net components.

In controller I have just returned view of the index.

here is my code for the view

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    //Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    var X = Html.X();
}
@Html.Label("Something")
@(Html.X().ResourceManager())
@(        
    Html.X().Window()
        .Layout(LayoutType.Border)
        .Items(Html.X().Panel()
        .Region(Region.North)
        .Items(Html.X()
            .Label()
            .Text("Compensation"))
        )
    )
```

the html helper is showing but the ext.net code does not seem to be working.I would appreciate any help. thanks

Comment: Can you upload your project somewhere so I can check it?

Answer (score 2):

Please, check that your web.config in the root (http://pastebin.com/K1c0K4jb) and web.config (http://pastebin.com/j6CyZXPG) in the Views folder have provided structure.

If you will continue experiencing this problem provide your web.config files